# Node.js server with http get json

Tags: node.js, http

I want to create a simple Node.js server to do the following :

With my application I just do the command `http.get(Node.Js_Server_address/json)` to get the json file data stored on my server.

Could please help me with a tutorial? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: There are lots of examples on this topic in various websites. Using search on stackoverflow would give the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple example of node.js server:

```
var app = require('./app');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("listening to: http://127.0.0.1:8080");
});

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

there is a nice tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/) and [here](https://howtonode.org/hello-node) ...
you can use [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node) to install node.js and all the packages that you need for it.
hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, so I can do ?
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/myFile.json');

Comment: basically yes, make sure you have installed all packages that you need. for example: npm (package manager), express etc. take a look here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express
You should send html files... 
**res.sendfile(__dirname + '/myFile.HTML');**

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I already installed everything (including express), and res.sendfile(__dirname + '/myFile.JSON'); is working very well, why would you suggest using html ?

Comment: great! :) 
you can use whatever you want, i though you need to send html files to your client.
please mark it as acceptable answer ;) tnx.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples on this topic, i think you should make some googling before next time.
You can create a REST server via express module of nodeJs. In your server folder use `npm install express` to download express module. You can get more information about express from [here](http://expressjs.com). After that create a `server.js` file in your server folder.In `server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var PORT = 8080;
/* req stands for request, res stands for response */
app.get('/json',function(req,res){
    res.json(yourData);
})

app.listen(PORT,function(){
    console.log('Express is listening port:' + PORT + '!');
})
```

So this should do the work. Let me know if this helps you.